# Attribute value is automatically inserted inside double quote

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to place html node as I have created. But when using JS and inserting inside `div` it single quotes changes to double quotes. Code is :

```
function createHederaObject(params){
    let Hederaobject =  '<hedera-micropayment '
        for(var i in params){
            if(params.hasOwnProperty(i) && i!=='attrID'){
                Hederaobject += i +"= '"+ params[i] + "' , " + "\n";
            }
        }

        Hederaobject += '></hedera-micropayment>';
        console.log(Hederaobject);

        var body = document.getElementById(params['attrID']);
        body.innerHTML += Hederaobject;
        //console.log((Hederaobject))
        return Hederaobject;
        //callback(Hederaobject);
    }
```

I should be exactly like this:

```
     <hedera-micropayment submissionnode= '0.0.1761' ,
        time= '1559313345' ,
        type= 'article' ,
        memo= '1275,79' ,
        paymentserver= 'http://localhost:9090/' ,
        recipientlist= '[{ "to": "0.0.99", "tinybars": "4666667" }]' ,
        contentid= '79' ,
        extensionid= 'ligpaondaabclfigagcifobaelemiena' ,
        redirect= '{ "nonPayingAccount": "/insufficient-amount/", "noAccount": "/account-not-paired/", "homePage": "/" }' ,></hederamicropayment>
```

But all the single quotes gets replace and become like this:

```
    <hedera-micropayment data-submissionnode="0.0.1761" ,="" data-time="1559313345" data-type="article" data-memo="1275,79" data-paymentserver="http://localhost:9090/" data-recipientlist="[{ &quot;to&quot;: &quot;0.0.99&quot;, &quot;tinybars&quot;: &quot;4666667&quot; }]" data-contentid="79" data-extensionid="ligpaondaabclfigagcifobaelemiena" data-redirect="{ &quot;nonPayingAccount&quot;: &quot;/insufficient-amount/&quot;, &quot;noAccount&quot;: &quot;/account-not-paired/&quot;, &quot;homePage&quot;: &quot;/&quot; }"></hedera-micropayment>
```

which created the problem while parsing data. In this particular one

```
  data-recipientlist= '[{ "to": "0.0.99", "tinybars": "4666667" }]' ,
```

I must have same structure.

How to keep the single quotes as it is. Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: just remove the double quotes, why you need em anyway?

Comment: Why does it cause a problem parsing the data? Use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: What's with the commas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the behavior is by design and doesn't pose any significant issue for development.

Comment: Remove the commas. The HTML parser is confused by them and adds them to the attribute values.

Comment: @James This html object is for a chrome extension, and it needs exact same structure. If I remove double quote it will give error. If I alter the quotes it gives error. So its not my choice. If I had to deal with the data, I could have done parsing or I could modify however I want.

Comment: @HereticMonkeyThank you for the response, I tried but didn't work. Thanks

Comment: @ScottMarcus Do you even understand the question ? Is it seem to be just design question really ? Or when It comes to html, for you, is it design by default?

Comment: @IsaacVidrine When I remove the quotes It give me this error : Unexpected token t in JSON at position 3, when I alter the quotes this error occurs : Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 3

Comment: I do understand the question and the fact is that the result of single quotes make no practical difference in any way. You say having single quotes causes a problem with parsing, but using `JSON.parse()` will work perfectly fine on that data structure. So really, what is the problem?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yeah, you are right. Thanks for helping. I had limited time so I had implemented the other way. But yeah it seems to me the quotes things should not cause any problem, the must be other issues. Sorry for that .

Answer (score 1):

This is just how `innerHTML` works - all 'string' nodes with attributes are converted to DOM tree - and when you read information from it (e.g. by browser 'inspect element' then DOM node attribute is converted to string with double quotes)

```js
document.body.innerHTML += `<div id='abc'>ABC</div>`;

console.log(abc);
```